# FloatingActionButton not showing fully in screen

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I have used FloatingActionButton in my application its not showing fully in the screen. I have used latest android design support library. Below i have paste my XML.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hsp.inventory"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.hsp.inventory.helper.PatchedScrollingViewBehavior"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_name" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_add"
    app1:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Output Image:

[image]

How can i resolve this issue. Screen shot taken Moto-g (Lollipop)

Comment: I thought it because you set its anchor view to your ViewPager. Try to remove it

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam Removed anchorview. same result coming

Comment: Do u override any of the params in code?

Comment: Or did u set any window flags for the activity?

Comment: @EE66 i did not override any params and i did not set any windows flag

Comment: Do you use fragments and fragment transactions in this example?

Comment: @NickCardoso no i'm using AppCompatActivity

Comment: set button out of view pager